# Ruby on Rails - Data not saved. Index showing blank values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, indexing, save

I'm creating a Ruby on Rails application but encountered a database problem. I have controller actions and views for the 'new' action but my values never get saved to the database unless I'm using Rails Console. My Rails version is 4.0.4. Here is my GamesController

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @games = Game.all
  end

  def show
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @game = Game.new
  end

  def create # This is the important method here.
    @game = Game.new(game_params)
  if @game.save
    redirect_to games_path, :notice => "Game was saved"
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

  def edit
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    if @game.save
      redirect_to @game
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    @game.destroy
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  end

  def game_params #Probably should use something inlace of :tags
    params.require(:game).permit(:tags)
  end
end
```

Here is my 'new' view, new.html.erb

```
<h2>Add a new game!</h2>
  <%= form_for @game do |f| %>
    <p>
  <%= f.label :title %></br>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.label :console %></br>
  <%= f.text_field :console %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.label :genre %></br>
  <%= f.text_field :genre %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.label :released_on %></br>
  <%= f.text_field :released_on %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

When I pass in the values to the new form, and click on submit (create action), I get redirected to the index page. Unfortunately, I see blank values for every field, meaning the data wasn't actually saved.

I tried testing with validations and validating only the title but it didn't work because the values were not saved. On the other hand, when I run rails console, I can create new instances of the games class and they get saved to the database. So I have no idea why it doesn't work on the form.

I've tried calling the create method with params[:game] and also with strong parameters. It never works, it just returns blank values

Here is my rake routes file

```
Games::Application.routes.draw do

  get "static_pages/about"
  get "static_pages/contact"
  get "static_pages/help"

  resources :games
end
```

By request, I will add my gemfile.

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.4'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

My question is how do I get these values to show up when submitting form data? Does it have something to do with my routes? I declared resources games to link the 7 RESTFUL routes on one line.

I know that POST requests are used for the create method. I find it puzzling, that it works in rails console, but not on the form.

I searched extensively on StackOverflow and found one answer regarding strong_params. Unfortunately, I incorporated that into my controller, and it still didn't work. I still think my problem lies in how I'm using strong_params.

I basically cut and pasted the code in that answer so it might not work in this case. I tried reading the documentation as well, but I couldn't understand it.

Comment: scroll down, it's under the destroy method

Comment: What is `tags` in permitted params?

Comment: You only allow attributes tags to be updated. It seems to be a relation. All the game attributes you want to define at creation should also be in game_params.

Comment: If you are using rails 4, try put `game_params` method under private method, read about [StrongParameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

Comment: right, I got that answer from Stack Overflow, but their answer didn't work, so I asked again here. I tried your method but it didn't work. I think, it's because I have .permit(:tags) but I don't know what I should put there instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be putting your **`attributes`** in the **`permitted params`**.Your `game_params` method should be like this

```
private
def game_params
  params.require(:game).permit(:title,:console,:genre,:released_on)
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem was I used .permit(:tags) and forgot completely the tags were supposed to be the columns in my table. It worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add all of your attributes on the new form to the strong params

```
def game_params
  params.require(:game).permit(:title, :console, :released_on, :genre)
end
```

see the guides for more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters